# Dimensions of C (1801, 3600) are incompatible with X (3600) and/or Y (1801); see help(pcolormesh)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pygrib

I'm looking to show surface wind data from "https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land?tab=form"

I'm using the code below to unpack the data in the form of a diagram
"https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/How+to+plot+GRIB+files+with+Python+and+matplotlib"

However I get the error 'TypeError: Dimensions of C (1801, 3600) are incompatible with X (3600) and/or Y (1801); see help(pcolormesh)', which should work as C is (rows, columns) and X represents columns and Y represents rows, but this error suggests the data does not fit?

The code is below, please any suggestions would be massively appreciated, thanks!

```py
import pygrib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import shiftgrid
import numpy as np
 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
 
grib = 'adaptor.mars.internal-1669570066.0148444-9941-17-702abb2d-e37e-4ef7-a19e-a04fb24e5a20.grib' # Set the file name of your input GRIB file
grbs = pygrib.open(grib)
 
grb = grbs.select()[0]
data = grb.values
 
# need to shift data grid longitudes from (0..360) to (-180..180)
lons = np.linspace(float(grb['longitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees']), \
float(grb['longitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees']), int(grb['Ni']) )
lats = np.linspace(float(grb['latitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees']), \
float(grb['latitudeOfLastGridPointInDegrees']), int(grb['Nj']) )
data, lons = shiftgrid(180., data, lons, start=False)
grid_lon, grid_lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) #regularly spaced 2D grid
 
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, \
    urcrnrlon=180.,llcrnrlat=lats.min(),urcrnrlat=lats.max(), \
    resolution='c')
    
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,60.),labels=[0,0,0,1])
    
x, y = m(grid_lon, grid_lat)

#x = np.transpose(x)
#y = np.transpose(y)

cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.gist_stern_r)
 
plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='vertical', shrink=0.5)
plt.title('CAMS AOD forecast') # Set the name of the variable to plot
plt.savefig(grib+'.png') # Set the output file name
```

However, even if I transpose the x and y data I get the same error type but: X (1801) and/or Y (3600). What ideally should happen is a map loads with North-South and East-West wind surface speeds.

[Numpy pcolormesh: TypeError: Dimensions of C are incompatible with X and/or Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791614/numpy-pcolormesh-typeerror-dimensions-of-c-are-incompatible-with-x-and-or-y)

Above is a similar question. However, the suggested transposing data solution which worked in that case did not work here.

Comment: The x and the y are the *boundaries* of your cells. So, there should be 3601 boundaries if there are 3600 cells in the x direction.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the response, would you by any chance know how to add these extra columns and rows? Many thanks! Sam

Comment: Now you do `lons = np.linspace(..., int(grb['Ni']) )`. It would make sense to add 1: `lons = np.linspace(..., int(grb['Ni']) + 1)`. And similar for `lats`.

Comment: @JohanC Hi, thanks very much for the suggestion, it looks like the approach works on Y, changing it to 1802 (from 1801), however modifying the X value this way instead (int(grb['Ni']) + 1) changes the lons array from (-180, ... , 180) to (0 , ... , 360), with grid_lat and grid_lon both staying at (1802, 3600)?